# Trigger Prow job reading parameters from the comment with some parameters

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, terraform, github-actions, testinfra

Git hub link to issue that i have raised:
https://github.com/kubernetes/test-infra/issues/25654

We have api tests that are triggered once user comments /test smoke on a PR request,but we want to make this job parametrized which will help run these tests with some parameter.

E.g /test smoke skip

Here we want utilise skip keyword in our job and take action accordingly.

This would enable jobs to run on some user based run time condition helping in creating less jobs.

As of now  i dont see any way to pass any parameter with PR comment which can be utilised.

Any workaround to execute the job with parameters would be helpful.